# Как сделать вывод интернет странички?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, borland

Как сделать в Delphi7 вывод интернет странички, типа `iframe` в `HTML`? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser)
- [Using The WebBrowser Component](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27843)